# Are Filtered Data Extensions also Part of the Attribute Group

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, attribute-group

I assume, but frankly I am not sure if the filtered Data- Extension used as entry point in a Journey is also linked to the same Attribute Group as the parent one I create the filter from. (The comment "Contact Builder uses this data extension as part of a data relationship" is not shown for filtered data Extension.)

Or  do I have to create the filter within the Journey in this case?

Comment: why would you need to have this DE as part of an attribute group?